# How can I download python .egg files, when behind a firewall

Tags: python, windows, linux, cygwin, turbogears

I'm going to try out turbogears however I'm on windows vista.
however due to firewall proxy problems, it seems i can't download .egg files which is required for setup turbogears to get installed in my windows environment.
I do have a bootable, or I can make a bootable Linux USB, I can try cygwin but I am not sure where to start with cygwin, so I was wondering what would solve my firewall / proxy problem of installing something like turbogears.

if it's possible, is there some non-online version of turbogears that i could just download from visiting a site and then somehow importing that non-online version into my python environment?

thanks so much!:)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the problem is not with the firewall per se, but with the fact that you need to use an HTTP proxy. If you do need to use a proxy, try setting the http_proxy environment variable. It might be that your firewall uses NTLM proxy authentication (which Python doesn't support); in this case, try setting up an [APS proxy server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) on your local machine, and point http_proxy to localhost.

Answer (score 3):

You can run TG [locally from windows](http://docs.turbogears.org/1.0/InstallWindows). The `tgsetup.py` method of installation uses [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c9) which depends on being able to bring in `.egg` files from the internet. The best approach would be to open the firewall to eggs, as others suggested. TG has a [list of egg files](http://www.turbogears.org/download/filelist.html) that you can try to bring manually (maybe from an open internet connection).
Installing an egg manually is possible, but [not recommended](http://www.turbogears.org/download/filelist.html).

If changing the firewall rules is not possible, you can use a Linux (bootable or virtual) installation that has a pre-configured TG package. For example, [Fedora has one](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/fedora/releases/9/Everything/i386/os/Packages/TurboGears-1.0.4.4-2.fc9.noarch.rpm). This way, the TG package crosses (hopefully) the firewall as an `.rpm` file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the old firewall hack... try throwing "?file.jpg" or "#file.jpg" on the end (sans quotes). The firewall may see this as you're trying to download an image file which it'll allow, the responding server probably won't care that you've attached a query string, and (I think) python will just see an egg.

Answer (score 1):

Add python to the firewall exceptions list. Just make sure you don't run any questionable code made in python, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for, but you can [bypass the proxy tunneling SSH](http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php).  Another possibility is using [Tor](http://tor.eff.org).